# After getting the permission soft keyboard does not show up for the first time

Tags: permissions, android-softkeyboard

I read all the similar questions but nothing useful in my case..
I have an activity which shows soft keyboard automatically when it is started.
It's working fluently with no error. But the issue is I need to use  permissions for this activity so when the first time activity is executed and permission is asked (then granted), softkeyboard does not show up no matter what (I even need to press edittext 2-3 times for it to load)
I can fix it with recreate() method obviously because it will be necessary only for one time but you know screen refreshing lag makes the application quality lower. Do you have any suggestion please? Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I decided to use recreate() method in onRequestPermissionsResult(). Since it will be executed only one time it was not a big issue so I decided to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way, and though it might not be helpful in your particular scenario, might help someone else. You can set windowSoftInputMode as stateAlwaysVisible for the activity in which you wish to see the keyboard after accpeting/denying permissions, and it will pop up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I was using the `Dexter` library, and I assume you are using it too.

**Solution for those who use the Dexter library:** you must call `token.continue Permission Request();` in the `onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown` event of your `PermissionListener`.

```
Dexter.withContext(activity)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            })
            .check();
```